# android uploading empty image to the host using php

Tags: php, android, kotlin, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a photo from an android device to host using PHP and base 64, bitmap ; but it uploads two empty images (it uploads two times) can't figure out why, any help or alternative way?

I'm uploading the photo in a register layout so I tried just inserting the photo without anything else, and I tried using another hosting service but unfortunately, nothing worked.

the name of the empty photo is inserted in the database yet in the file manager it's an empty photo

the php code;

```php
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$user_image= $_POST['user_image'];
$user_name= $_POST['user_name'];
$user_email= $_POST['user_email'];
$user_un= $_POST['user_un'];
$user_pass= $_POST['user_pass'];

$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "...";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

$ra=rand(0,20000);
$rn=rand(0,40000);
$rd=rand(0,60000);
$imgname = "pl".$ra.$rn.$rd.".jpeg";
$decoding=base64_decode("$user_image");
file_put_contents("images/".$imgname,$decoding);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name,user_email,user_un,user_pass,user_image)
        VALUES ('$user_name','$user_email','$user_un','$user_pass','$imgname')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $UserId = $conn->insert_id;

        $response['dishs'] = array();

        $hobbie['status'] = "ok";
        $hobbie['result'] = "Welcome";

        // push single dishinto final response array
        array_push($response['dishs'],$hobbie);
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);


} else {
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
        $response['dishs'] = array();
        // failed to insert row

        $hobbie['status'] = "no";
        $hobbie['result'] = "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
        array_push($response['dishs'],$hobbie);
        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

the kotlin code

these are defined in the head of the class

```
"class RegisterPage :Fragment() {
    var encodImg = ""
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
......
"
```

sending this to the host

```
"...      val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["user_image"] = encodImg
...
"
```

the way i choose the photo from gallery and encrypt

```
    private fun startGallery() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
        if (galleryIntent.resolveActivity(activity!!.packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1000)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, i: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val uri: Uri? = i!!.data

            change_profile_photo.setImageURI(uri)
            manageImageFromUri(i.data!!)

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun manageImageFromUri(imageUri: Uri) {
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            Snackbar.make(view!!, "ERROR", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        } else {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver, imageUri)
            bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
            val b = baos.toByteArray()
            encodImg = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attack. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Enable error reporting for the php, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you i know that but it's just a training project and im still learning.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner error reporting is enabled and no errors are showing

Comment: any good tutorials for uploading images to PHP host?